# omniauth gowalla strategy error: comparison of String with Bignum failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth, omniauth

as far as  I can get gowalla auth code response contains both `expires_at` and `expires_in` but
expires_at is not valid date string so it throws error while comparing dates
any idea to hack omniauth or gowalla strategy would be very welcome!!!

rails 3.0.9
ruby 1.9.2

```
comparison of String with Bignum failed
oauth2 (0.5.0) lib/oauth2/access_token.rb:72:in `<'
oauth2 (0.5.0) lib/oauth2/access_token.rb:72:in `expired?'
oa-oauth (0.3.0) lib/omniauth/strategies/oauth2.rb:67:in `callback_phase'


{
"scope":"read",
"expires_at":"Sun, 09 Oct 2011 12:47:37 -0000",
"username":"altuure",
"expires_in":1172767,
"refresh_token":"XX",
"access_token":"XX" 
}
```

Comment: sorry for delay but I commited the patch to the github you can find the details over here https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/issues/485

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry for delay but I commited the patch to the github you can find the details over here http://github.com/intridea/omniauth/issues/485 –

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use whatever you can.  `expires_in` appears to be an interval, so you can do:

```
expires_at = Time.now + json["expires_in"].to_i
```

That said, the date string for `expires_at` definitely parses in 1.9.2-p290 (using `DateTime.parse(str)`).  There's always `DateTime.strptime` if you need to parse a date/time string according to a given format.